# New Session is created for ajax call once deployed. But not on dev project why is this?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

I've been on the hunt for a solution for an issue that I discovered whilst trying to deploy a project Ive been working on.

Everything works fine on the development test visual studio build but when i upload it to my iis 7 server and Ajax call that i have seems to have no session(they are null). I use the session to store my user. Ill past my code below can anyone see anything wrong with it?

```
    public JsonResult matchMaker(string request)
    {
        try
        {
            getCurrentUser();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return null;
        }
        // nothing needed below cut it out as note relevant.
    }
    private void getCurrentUser()
    {
        // debug this
        HttpSessionStateBase a = Session;
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            try
            {
                // If a noUserInSessionEx is throw it will redirect them to login gracefully - Should also log why 
                if (Session["CurrentUser"] != null)
                {
                    currentUser = (UserModel)Session["CurrentUser"];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new noUserInSession("No user for current session");
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                Response.Redirect("login");
            }
        }
    }
```

On my index page where the above method is being called via javascript i have

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Write("Session variables: <br>") ;
        for( var i=0 ; i <Session.Contents.Count ; i++){
            Response.Write(Session.Contents[i].ToString() + "<br>");
        }
        getCurrentUser();
        Response.Write(currentUser.Email);
        return View();
    }
```

Javascript is as below

```
    function executeAJAXRequest(datain, url) {
    returnObj = false;
    if (url != "" && datain != "") {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache:false,
            url: "http://localhost:51525/ajaxRequest/" + url,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "request=" + JSON.stringify(datain)
        })
        request.done(function (e) {
            //console.log("Sucessful Ajax:" + datain + " TO: " + url + "\n ResponseJSON: " + arguments[2].responseText);
            returnObj = eval(arguments[0]);
        });
        request.fail(function (textStatus) {
            console.log("Failure 2 Ajax (:()\n\n Data: " + datain
                                             + "\n TO: " + url +
                                            "\n ERROR: " + textStatus.statusText);
            returnObj = false;
        });
        return returnObj;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failure 2 Ajax (:() No Info");
        return returnObj;
    }
}
```

It shows me that correct user is stored and displays the email
How ever my ajax is responding with the redirect to the login page.

The session has a different id to the ajax session.

Im so lost :S any help would be mega awesomeo :)

Comment: Just to clarify - session object is null and NullReferenceException is thrown or it just an empty for ajax call?

Comment: A good question. The session object is not null and the keys are there but the keys values are null. Perhaps a new session is starting... im looking into it.

Comment: Yep every time its hit it creates a new session. :( Why would this be?

Comment: Each request has ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. Based on it Asp.Net session mechanism works. Asp.Net creates it for the first request. You can check in browser developer tools, are usual and ajax request have this cookie, and is value for them are the same. If it wont' be the same, then somehow it creates new session each time...

Comment: I can see the post has a different session id to the one I print on the page why is this?

Comment: When do you do this ajax call? On the first page? Do you have some specific session settings in web.config? maybe specific Domain value for session cookie?

Comment: On the page after i log in the user click s a button and it fires a request. It works fine in visual studio but once i deploy it does not.

Ill add the ajax above

Comment: Also in my web config the only thing that relates to session is <sessionState timeout="30" /> i think.

Comment: You can try to check with Fiddler\Browser developer tools, when this cookie is lost. Initially you open login page without any cookies. After login Asp.Net will return new cookie. then you open next page, and do ajax call. Somewhere in this worklow cookie is lost. You can try to use Fiddler\etc to find where it lost, and when Asp.Net returns new cookie.

Comment: The cookie isnt lost because when i navigate to another page i get the same session id it is only for ajax calls that a new session id gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so turns out the only issue I was having was I didn't have http:// in front of my address for ajax. This cause a new session to be created. Apparently not an issue when using local host thanks for the help Sergey :)